# eslint: enforcing blank lines between method names?

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

We are wanting to add blank line between before function declarations and class methods, using eslint, but we can't seem to work out the right rule.

This should cause an error:

```
class MyClass {
  myProp1: string;
  myProp2: string;
  method1 () {
  }
  method2 () {
  }
}
```

But not this, since there is a line break between methods (note we don't want to enforce line breaks between other fields):

```
class MyClass {
  myProp1: string;
  myProp2: string;

  method1 () {
  }

  method2 () {
  }
}
```

So far we have this which works for functions, but it does not seem to work for methods:

```js
  'lines-between-class-members': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/lines-between-class-members': ['error',
      { blankLine: 'always', prev: ['*'], next: ['function', 'block']}
  ],
```

Can anyone suggest how we can go about this?

Comment: the problem is, how to differentiate among method declaration and var declarations?

Comment: I would imagine this would be a class level named block, vs any a non-block line?